# Child tag's CSS property can have significant impact on parent tag

Tags: css

I have created a page that has a fixed header when it is scrolled. It works fine, thanks to a certain border property.

**Permanent screen header - how it works**

The page has two headers, one for the page when it is not scrolled, and one for the scrolled page, I gave them ids as respectively pageheader and screenheader.

The default box model is changed to border-box in the CSS, and the headers and the main content is laid out using the position and z-index elements.

The page has 3 layers. The headers are in the two upper layers. The third layer in the bottom contains the main content and the footer.

```
   1____ __               Pageheader with title and topline (z-index: 2) - scrollable
   2__                    Topline (z-index: 1) - not scrollable
   3       ___________ __ The main content and the footer (z-index: unspecified, that is 0) - scrollable
```

The first layer is the upper layer in the z-index stack and the topmost content on the page. This layer contains the title and the topline. The middle layer contains the screenheader. This is always placed topmost on the screen (position: fixed), and on the z-index layer underneath the pageheader. The lower layer contains the main content followed by the footer.

To start with you can not see the fixed screenheader, it is hidden by the upper pageheader layer. Scrolling do not affect the screenheader, so it becomes visible when you scroll the pageheader out of the screen.

The page content will also be scrolled out of the screen, but under the screenheader in the z-index stack. This way you will always have a header on the page or screen.

**How come?**

The strange and tricky part of the code lies in the border property on the pageheader. If you take that away the whole idea is broken.

The screenheader will be visible above - not covered by - the pageheader, and, which is really tricky, the screenheader's parent, the wrapper, will be placed after its screenheader child! Furthermore the h1 tag seems to lose its vertical margins in the content div.

And that is what my question is about, how come?

A demo can be seen on http://ovovow.dk/fixedtop